# Data migration from Oracle Database Clob to GCP Bucket

Tags: oracle, google-cloud-platform, blob, clob, bucket

A scenario where data migration is needed from an Oracle Database, where application data is stored in a CLOB (Character Large Object) format, which could include files in formats such as PDF, XML, Base64, PNG, etc. The goal is to migrate these CLOB data into a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Bucket.

Any ideal for above problem statement